# python datetime.strftime() fails to stringify datetime object with RqlTzinfo

Tags: rethinkdb, python-datetime, rethinkdb-python

My fetched rows from rethinkdb cluster include date objects with timezones.
Here's an example of one:

```
ipython> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 18, 0, 22, 4, 644000, tzinfo=<rethinkdb.ast.RqlTzinfo object at 0x7f072c5d6250>)
```

I'm trying to stringify them into a certain format:

```
dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S (%Z)")
```

and it leads to

```
*** TypeError: tzinfo.tzname() must return None or a string, not 'unicode'
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [`RqlTzinfo.tzname()`](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/02d4e6f6d454b2f7dd719e288c604d5c038fcd11/drivers/python/rethinkdb/ast.py#L669), you can see that it simply returns its `offsetstr` attribute. Since that attribute is never modified or converted anywhere in that class and the class's behavior does not depend on it being either a `str` or `unicode`, the following should suffice:

```
dt.tzinfo.offsetstr = str(dt.tzinfo.offsetstr)
```

Comment: WHY didn't I take a look in the source code in the first place..? The name of the attribute is offsetstr by the way, or at least in the version I'm using (v1.15 - old), but anyways, thanks, I feel so stupid now :P